# No hace autentificacion en firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tuve problemas con un proyecto en el cual estaba haciendo autentificacion con firebace estaba usando el correo electronico y google como autentificaciones, 
Empece otro proyecto, también cree otro proyecto en `firebase` y me use los mismos códigos que antes si me funcionaban a esta nueva aplicación y también puse los compile necesarios y no me hace la autentificación, si quiero registrar un correo no me deja y si inicio sesión con google me manda un toast que yo hice de error y en el firebase no me guarda ese inicio de sesión .

----build app-----

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
//Firebaase
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.2'
//suport
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

----Codigo para iniciar sesión con google

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();


    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Algo Salio Mal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso).build();



    btnCuenta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),CorreoElectronico.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btnCorreo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),CorreoElectronico.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}

private void inicializarAutenticacion() {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser usr = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(usr != null)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
}



private void cerrarSesionFirebase()
{
    mAuth.signOut();
}




private void goMainScreen() {
    // Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
    Intent in = new Intent();
    in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(in);
}


// GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
//     .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
//   .requestEmail()
// .build();
private void signIn()
{
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent,RC_SIGN_IN);
}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);



    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN)
    {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if(result.isSuccess())
        {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Autentificacion Fallida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(),null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()  {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                Log.d( "TAG", "signInWithCredential:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                // updateUI(user);

            }else{
                Log.w("TAG","signWithCredential:failure",task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Autentificacion fallida", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //updateUI(null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

------------Codigo para iniciar con correo y contraseña

```
 createUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            userEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
            userPass = password.getText().toString().trim();
            if(userEmail.equals("") || userPass.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(CorreoElectronico.this, "Se dejaron campos vacios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userPass))
            {
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail,userPass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        // startActivity(new Intent(CorreoElectronico.this,Main2Activity.class));
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                            Toast.makeText(CorreoElectronico.this, "Usuario Creado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(CorreoElectronico.this, "Error al Crear el Usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


        }
        });



    //move to login
    login.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
        //startActivity(new Intent(CorreoElectronico.this,Main2Activity.class));

        userEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
        userPass = password.getText().toString().trim();

        if(userEmail.equals("")||userPass.equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(CorreoElectronico.this, "Existen Campos Vacios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(userEmail) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(userPass))
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(CorreoElectronico.this, Main2Activity.class));
                        Toast.makeText(CorreoElectronico.this, "Bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(CorreoElectronico.this, "Fallo al Ingresar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

    });



}
```

Comment: Buenas Luis, incluiste tu nueva aplicación, es decir, el nombre del paquete de la nueva app, en tu proyecto de firebase junto con su correspondiente Json del paquete?

Answer (score 0):

Además del código, el nuevo proyecto debería incluir el archivo de configuración ( google-services.json ) que corresponde al proyecto nuevo. Este archivo tiene configuraciones específicas que le permiten acceder a los servicios de Firebase para cada proyecto y package id de aplicación.